# Prove the probability that X takes on an even value for a Poisson R.V.?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution

We have a random variable $X$ that is distributed according to the Poisson distribution with $ \lambda$, such that $P[X=k]=e^{-\lambda}\frac{ \lambda^k}{k!}$ for $k=0,1,\dots$.

We want to show that probability that $X$ takes on an even value is $\frac{1+e^{-2\lambda}}{2}$.

I am thinking that the identities $e^{t}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^k}{k!}$ and $e^{-t}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{-t^{k}}{k!}$ could be used, namely through a system of equations, but I need help figuring out how to productively do this.

Comment: Possibly related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472431/probability-that-an-integer-number-having-poisson-distribution-is-even

Comment: I did look at this link, but thank you! I'm following the point of $e^{-t}+e^{t}$, but I don't quite know how to tie it together to get the final value $\frac{1+e^{-2\lambda}}{2}$.

Comment: multiply by $e^{-\lambda}$ you left out.