# Probability that $X$ is even for a Poisson?

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-distribution

I know that this question has been asked several times, and to my knowledge I have read through all the versions. However, I can't find a complete proof, and I am having trouble finishing the algebraic manipulation. If anyone could help, I'd really appreciate it.

We have a r.v. $X$ that is poisson distributed with $\lambda$. So:

$P[X=k]=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$ for $k=0,1,\dots$.

We want to find that the probability of $X$ taking on an even value.

So far, I have:

$$e^{t}+e^{-t}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^k}{k!}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-t)^k}{k!}$$

$$=2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$

I know that the final answer is $$\frac{1+e^{-2\lambda}}{2}$$, but I am struggling with getting there.

Comment: The correct version for the powerseries of $e^x$ is $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}$ (so $t^k!$ above doesn't make sense, since the factorial is defined only for positive integers, including $0$). So:   $$e^t+e^{-t}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n+(-t)^n}{n!}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1+(-1)^n}{n!}t^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2}{(2n)!}t^{2n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2}{(2n)!}t^{2n}$$ since 1^n+(-1)^n equals 2 for n even and 0 for n odd (meaning that the only $n$"s that survive after the cancelations are the even ones.

Comment: Canonical answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472431/probability-that-an-integer-number-having-poisson-distribution-is-even

Comment: @NikolaosSkout I fixed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability you want is

$$ P=\sum_{k \,{\rm even}}P(X=k)= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{2j}}{(2j)!}$$

But you know that, for any $\lambda$

$$ \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{2j}}{(2j)!}= \frac{e^{\lambda}+e^{-\lambda}}{2}$$

Hence... (what's your problem?)...

Comment: That's embarrassing. Not sure what my problem is. Thanks for your help.