# Functions of discrete random variables: inverting Poisson

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ be a discrete random variable having the Poisson distribution
>   with parameter $\lambda$ and let $Y=|\sin (\frac{\pi}{2}X)|$. Find the
>   mass function of $Y$.

We are given the probability mass function of $X$:
$$
\mathbb{P}(X=x) = \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}e^{-\lambda}.
$$

It will be useful to express $X$ in terms of the new random variable $Y$:
$$
X = \begin{cases}
\frac{2}{\pi} \arcsin Y \qquad & \text{if } 0\le Y \le 1 \\
0 \qquad &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
We need to remove the negative part of the arcsine since $Y$ is defined as an absolute value.

Let me try to compute the probability mass function of $Y$:
$$
p_Y(y) = \mathbb{P}(Y=y) = \mathbb{P}(|\sin (\frac{\pi}{2} X)|=y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{\lambda^{\frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin y}}{(\frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin y)!} e^{-\lambda} & \text{if } 0\le y \le 1\\
e^{-\lambda} & \text{if } y < 0.
\end{cases}
$$

I think my attempt is wrong because the probability mass function for $Y$ I just derived shows a factorial of a number that is highly unlikely to be a natural number.

Edit: after Frpzzd's answer, I guess the correct answer would be:
$$
p_Y(y) =
\begin{cases}
 \lambda e^{-\lambda} &\text{if } y=\sin\frac{\pi}{2}=1 \\
 e^{-\lambda} & \text{if } y=0.
\end{cases}
$$
I am still puzzled though, as $p_Y$ does not sum up to 1.

Edit 2: After Did's comment, I think I see what is going on now. Since $X\in\mathbb{N}$, we see that $Y$ can only take the values $0$ or $1$, and I now edited my previous question to show this.

To conclude the solution, I guess that we just have to redefine the probability distribution as:
$$
p_Y(y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda} & \text{if }y=1 \\
\frac{1}{1+\lambda} & \text{if }y=0,
\end{cases}
$$
so that $p_Y$ does sum up to 1?

Comment: Hmmm... Even after having been pointed to the fact, you still believe that $P(Y=\sin(2/\pi))\ne0$ where $Y=|\sin(\pi X/2)|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is almost correct, but your PMF is not defined for all values of $y$ between $0$ and $1$; it is only defined for those values of $y$ for which $\arcsin(y)\in\mathbb N$, since $X\in\mathbb N$.Thus, you only need to tweak the conditions on your piecewise definition of $p_Y(y)$ a little bit.

Comment: I guess you meant "for those values of $y$ for which $\frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin(y)\in\mathbb{N}$"?

Comment: @J.D. Right. $\space\space$

Answer (score 1):

To begin:

(1) $p_Y(y)=\mathbb P(Y=y)=\mathbb P(|\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}X)|=y)=\mathbb{P}(X=\frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin y)$

Since $X\in \mathbb{N} \text { and } y=|\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}X)|, Y \in \{0,1\}.$ Note that all even $X$ lead to $y=0$, so:

(2) $p_Y(y)
=\begin{cases}
\sum_{n}^\infty\mathbb P(X=2n)&\text{if } y = 0\\
1-\sum_{n}^\infty\mathbb P(X=2n)&\text{if }y = 1\\
\end{cases}$

By using the [formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472431/probability-that-an-integer-number-having-poisson-distribution-is-even) for the probability of the Poisson Distribution being even and the [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions#Useful_relations) $\cosh \lambda + \sinh \lambda =e^\lambda$, we get

(3) $p_Y(y)=\begin{cases}
e^{-\lambda}\cosh\lambda&\text{if } y = 0\\
e^{-\lambda}\sinh\lambda&\text{if }y = 1\\
\end{cases}$